# What kind of code could it be?

Tags: binary, base64, hex

I have some challange here and I want to extract some files out of a binary file. I know there are a couple of files inside. The first thing I see is an E-Mail and afterwards an attachment. It looks like base64 but there is this character (a simple point)-> . which is typically not allowed within base64. did someone of you have ever seen this?

i thought it could be some trick so i started to delete all foreign characters. After decoding i find tons of garbage and nothing that can be interpreted. no archivers were working, no streams were found, no strings, nothing. i suppose it has something to do with the . character but i have no idea.

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Every 76 character is a . It is the maximum encoded line length for some base64 variants. If you want to decode it just delete them and do not worry to loose information.